# How to test gradle code from build.gradle

Tags: gradle

There is more and more gradle code in my build.gradle.

The question is how to test gradle code from build.gradle. Is there any convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is convention but what You need to do is to make use of gradle tooling API. Basically it enables to You to load a `build.gradle` file, execute various tasks and verify the output. This code may be written as a normal test classes. You can find examples of such testing [here](https://github.com/apphance/Apphance-MobilE-Build-Automation/blob/59b168b5a10465e26ff238eeda333cb54c1630d1/src/test/groovy/integration/com/apphance/flow/plugins/ios/buildplugin/IOSPluginSpec.groovy) and [here](https://github.com/apphance/Apphance-MobilE-Build-Automation/blob/59b168b5a10465e26ff238eeda333cb54c1630d1/src/test/groovy/functional/com/apphance/flow/ios/ExecuteIosBuildsSpec.groovy) for instance. Tests are written in spock.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, code in `build.gradle` isn't tested. Instead, reusable/generic parts of the code are factored out into plugins and tasks implemented as classes, which are more amenable to testing.

A potential alternative is to test a task `A` by adding a task `testA` that depends on `A` and checks the outcome of `A`.

Comment: I think that tasks in build.gradle should be tested. It would be nice to separate test tasks from build.gradle.